# android tutorial pubsub problem

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have installed the pubsub android tutorial on an android device and have it connect to an external roscore on ubuntu desktop.
When I run *rostopic list* on ubuntu desktop, the "chatter" topic is listed. But when I publish data on this topic, the rosTextView on android unchange. However, run *rostopic echo /chatter* display the data I published.

Would you know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59561/android-tutorial-pubsub-problem/) by [Gosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4354/gosu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check that your NodeConfiguration is using a public address and that the master URI is correct. Also check ROS_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI on your desktop machine.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4354/gosu/) on 2013-05-07**:
Thanks alot! Its worked